# why h1 tag is rendering normal size text in react/nextjs?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

In my react app whereever i place h1 tag it just showing a normal font. On inspecting i found that my text is rendering as h1 but style of h1 is

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
}
```

I also tried to change this in my global.css

```
h1{
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

But it did not work. So how to render h1 as heading 1 text and font size

Comment: Try a !important.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably because you're using Tailwind base styles.

Check your main .css file. You should see the following at the top:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

This loads a set of preconfigured base styles in your css and includes unstyled headings.

You can read about all the style changes Tailwind base styles bring and the reasons for them here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight.

Answer (score 0):

```css
h1{
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<h1>Example</h1>
```

Comment: You can also use em/rem units.

Comment: It is recommended to add your description for the answer you posted

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the problem of specificity. Your global.css rules are being overridden by more specific rules. And from the available information, I don't know what or where those rules are.

This will help you understand better: [MDN CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: I have not specified any specific style anywhere. However my app is wrapped in chakra provider. h1 is not working anywhere in my app at any page... so this shows that it is not related to any specific style at any page

Comment: @user82554 Then perhaps chakra is overruling global.css. To check,  Is `<h1 style="font-size: large;font-weight:900;">...</h1>` working? If it is, then it's certain. In that case, I suggest you using inline style or `!important` keyword, or perhaps look the docs to solve it from that framework ;-)

Comment: I checked about chakra also, I pull up h1 out of chakra -provider it still not working. however !important in global.css does work. I still want to know why it is not working by default.